# Probability with or without replacement is more of a true fraction to 1/2

Tags: probability

[image: Need solution verification for all of them]

1a) 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

1b) 0/9, 1/9, 2/9, 3/9, 4/9

1c) 0/9, 1/9, 2/8, 3/7, 4/6

1d) Sample with replacement would give a better estimation to the true fraction of ½ because every trial will have the same percentage of outcome. For instance, if we have 3 marbles: 2 blue, 1 red. If we randomly choose one marble their outcome would be as follows -
Blue: 66% ⅔
Red: 33% ⅓

In hindsight, the probabilities aren’t exactly 50/50 visually. But, If you consider the fact that each time you choose a marble. The options you get are always the same or you can say it’s 50/50

Comment: Please type out images. They are not searchable, among other issues. Also, please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Remember that you are selecting four machines.  It looks like you calculated the probability of selecting a single machine in part b.  I am not sure what you did in part c.